# How to access image file in assets folder? [angular 7]

Tags: angular

I created an angular app with 'ng new my-app', folder structure is like so:

```
my-app
  |- e2e
  |- node_modules
  |- src
     |- assets
         |- images
             |- smile.jpg
```

How can I reach my image through the client
with `http://localhost:4200/images/smile.jpg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

If you want to open image from browser url then use this

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/images/smile.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: http://localhost:4200/assets/images/smile.jpg doesn't work. It just refers me back to http://localhost:4200/

Comment: Make sure image name must be right other wise it will redirect to `localhost:4200`.